# Unable to initialize main class in jar

Tags: java, maven

I need to create a launchable jar. To do this I added maven-jar-plugin to the pom in the plugins

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <configuration>                   
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <mainClass>main.MyClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

when I run this jar on the command line it displays

> C:\Users\user\git\myfolder\target>java -jar myprojectname-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> Error: Unable to initialize main class main.MyClass
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException

If I export a jar through Eclipse specifying the main class, then in the manifest the main class is indicated as main.MyClass and in this case the jar is launched.

The whole content of pom

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.user</groupId>
    <artifactId>myprojectname</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.java.version>1.8</project.java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${project.java.version}</source>
                    <target>${project.java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>

                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>setup/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>                 
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>main.MyClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you verify the project dependencies are packed as well inside the jar (or alternatively, when you launch the app from the jar that you're including any dependencies through the class path option)? It looks like some `org.openqa.selenium.`* dependency can't be found at runtime?

Comment: This jar contains only the classes of the project classes. You have to setup the classpath of the command line or build an uber jar (jar-with-dependencies)

Comment: You are focussing on the wrong thing. Your build is fine, your main class is in the manifest and being run as you wish. That's not the problem. The problem is: Your code requires certain libraries to run - in your case, selenium, at least. Your build isn't including these jars. They should be fatjarred in, or, more likely, simply add the jar name to the `Class-Path` entry in the manifest and ensure the selenium jar is next to your app jar when you launch it.

Answer (score 1):

You can build bigjar like there to your jar contain other dependencies:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.krzywanski.table.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

full pom you can find here: [Working pom](https://github.com/kamilkrzywanski/typedTable/blob/master/pom.xml)

Or contain dependencies in other directory like there:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>my.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <outputDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And put dependencies in "lib" directory under pom
[image]